# Is there anyway to set up automated build task in Team Services for ".xproj" .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, build-definition

I my team and I are using Visual Studio 2015, Team Services to build and manage a .NET Core application with multiple .NET Core class libraries all of which are ".xproj" projects. We are now looking to move away from manual builds and follow the continious integration and deployment approach. When adding a build task in Team Services there is a template option for building .NET Core applications. When selected I can see that the restore and build jobs are auto populated with the .csproj extension.

[image]

I have changed these to xproj and ran a build only to get the following error for each project in the solution.

Test.xproj'. The file type was not recognized.
2017-05-31T07:24:59.1375560Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1

How can I set up a build definition for xproj .NET Core projects?
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: csproj was reintroduced in Visual Studio 2017, you could either update to that locally and merge your projects over to the new format, or you could use an older version of NET Core's SDK and VS 2015 to build your xproj projects on VSTS.

Comment: Also note that support for VS 2015 ends on October 10th, 2017. The xproj/project.json tooling was never officially supported ("preview"). Though it is possible to set up CI/CD in VSTS for this, you are better off migrating now before you need to change the CI/CD setup again.

Comment: I can't find a task to use an older version of the NET Core SDK. I can only find the older DNX tasks in the marketplace. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KirKone.vsts-dnx-tasks

Comment: Are you using a custom build agent, or hosted? If it's custom then you can RDP and install a specific version of NET Core tools, if it's hosted then you'll either have to upgrade, or use a Visual Studio build task and set the VS version to 2015, but please bear in mind that you **will** come across this issue again over Martin's comment regarding VS 2015 support, and at that time it could be that your solution is larger and possibly has a bit of complexity around merging to VS 2017.

Comment: @ColinM Using a hosted build agent. Just tried a Visual Studio Build task and switched version to be 2015. The main reason for not upgrading to 2017 is to do with some of the team not being able to upgrade right now. I presume it is not possible for teams to work on a NET Core project if members are using different versions of VS.

Comment: Did switching to Visual Studio build with version 2015 work? It is possible, but will require some tweaks in your build - and working toward an upgrade/merge to 2017 which would include resolving any team blockers.

Comment: No switching to 2015 did not work. I am going to install 2017 and try a build with the converted project.

Comment: Be sure to check this post out when you migrate, this caused me issues where my project had stuck with packages.config but my build was looking for `PackageReference` Xml Elements for Nuget packages https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28056/vs-2017-still-uses-packagesconfig.html

Comment: @psycho can you build successfully after migrate your project from VS2015 to VS2017?

Comment: I was able to get the build to work after converting to VS2017 but I also changed the build agent to Hosted VS 2017.